# How to enhance C++ array performance at massive access

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, loops, stdvector

I'm working on a function which will be called about 240000000 times. In that function, I will access three vectors just one time each. like:

```
aj = a_[j];
bj = b_[j];
cj = c_[j];
```

All the vectors are defined in the same class, having 999 elements, which type is doule. It takes about 60s to finish the job.
But if I change vector access to three double variables, the time will reduce to 10s. like:

```
aj = fa;
bj = fb;
cj = fc;
```

If I change vector to array, it help less, using about 50s.
Why the time gap is so large? I think array access only involve index caculate.
Any idea about that?

**Add some code and data:**

1、To compare, consider 4 cases: original vector data; faked array which filled with almost the real data(I also checked the faked vector, it works almost the same with faked array); variables as class member; local variables.
I add them in the class(init them when construct) and function defination,
class defination:

```
        class CoefficientHolder {
      public:
        explicit CoefficientHolder(Size n)
        : n_(n), primitiveConst_(n-1), a_(n-1), b_(n-1), c_(n-1),
          monotonicityAdjustments_(n), fra{0.000000, 0.000000, ...},
 frb{0.000000, -0.001426, ...}, frc {0.000000, 0.000063, 0.000002, ...}
          {
            fa = 0.00134;
            fb = 0.00001;
            fc = 0.00002;
            fake_a_={0.000000, 0.000000, -0.007229, ...};
            fake_b_={0.000000, -0.001426, 0.000026, ...};
            fake_c_={0.000000, 0.000063, 0.000002, ...};
          }

        std::vector<Real> a_, b_, c_;   // original data, Real is redefination of double
        mutable Real fra[999], frb[999], frc[999]; // faked array
        mutable Real fa, fb, fc;        //faked variables
    };
```

function defination:

```
            Real value(Real x) const {
            static unsigned long long i = 0;
            GET_TIME_NS(start); // Get current time in nanosecond
            Size j = this->locate(x);
            Real dx_ = x-this->xBegin_[j];
            // Local faked variables
            //Real lfa = 0.01+0.002;
            //Real lfb = 0.00001 + 0.00000001;
            //Real lfc = 0.000000001 + 0.0000000000001;
            /*Check local variables performance*/
            //Real ret = this->yBegin_[j] + dx_*(lfa + dx_*(lfb + dx_*lfc));
            /*Check variables as class memeber performance*/
            //Real ret = this->yBegin_[j] + dx_*(fa + dx_*(fb + dx_*fc));
            /*Check faked variable performance*/
            //Real ret = this->yBegin_[j] + dx_*(fra[j] + dx_*(frb[j] + dx_*frc[j]));
            /*The real data performance*/
            Real ret = this->yBegin_[j] + dx_*(a_[j] + dx_*(b_[j] + dx_*c_[j]));
            CAL_NS_GAP(start, gap); // calculate time gap
            ++i;
            CALogger* g_logger = CALogger::GetInstance();
            static unsigned long long time_sum = 0;
            if(i >= 3000 && i < 53000)
            {
                g_logger->writeLog(std::to_string(i) + ":"  + std::to_string(gap));
                time_sum += gap;
            }
            if (i == 53000)
                g_logger->writeLog("###mean for 50000:"  + std::to_string(time_sum/50000));

            static unsigned long long time_sum1 = 0;
            if(i >= 50000000 && i < 50050000)
            {   
                g_logger->writeLog(std::to_string(i) + ":"  + std::to_string(gap));
                time_sum1 += gap;
            }
            if (i == 50050000)
                g_logger->writeLog("###mean for 50000:"  + std::to_string(time_sum1/50000));

time_sum2/time_sum3/time_sum4
```

I counted nanosecond they consumed and take 5 * 50000 samples in each case. It looks local variables works nearly same with class member variable, but much bettter than faked array; Faked array works nearly same with original data.

**Test result**(Eache case have 5 sets, each set have 50000 samples, which only display the mean value)：

original data(303.8):
mean for 50000:341
mean for 50000:306
mean for 50000:294
mean for 50000:295
mean for 50000:283

faked array(246.8):
mean for 50000:278
mean for 50000:246
mean for 50000:243
mean for 50000:234
mean for 50000:233

local faked variables(179):
mean for 50000:196
mean for 50000:176
mean for 50000:170
mean for 50000:189
mean for 50000:164

faked variables as class member(151.6):
mean for 50000:168
mean for 50000:142
mean for 50000:156
mean for 50000:147
mean for 50000:145

**More infor**
After I changed three vector to one struct vector, performance get better, but not enough:
code：

```
typedef struct st_factor
{
    Real a_;
    Real b_;
    Real c_;
    st_factor() : a_(0), b_(0), c_(0) {}
}STFACTOR;
typedef std::vector<STFACTOR> VFACTOR;
```

Test result(226.2):
mean for 50000:225
mean for 50000:225
mean for 50000:228
mean for 50000:221
mean for 50000:232

**Add another set of test result for different fake vector sizes**
I tried fake vectors with different sizes:1000/500/100/50/10
1000 and 500 almost same, final mean is about 190ns
100 is about 100ns
50 is about 85ns
10 is about 60ns
code:

```
    namespace QuantLib {
    typedef struct st_factor
    {
        Real a_;
        Real b_;
        Real c_;
        .......
    }STFACTOR;
    typedef std::vecotr<STFACTOR> VFACTOR;
        class CoefficientHolder {
          public:
            explicit CoefficientHolder(Size n)
            : m_fakeVf(TSZ),
              {
               m_fakeVf = {STFACTOR(0.01, 0.0002, 0),};
              }
  }

 Real value(Real x) const {
  Size j = this->locate(x);
  j = j%TSZ;
  GET_TIME_NS(start);
  Real fa = m_fakeVf[j].a_;
  Real fb = m_fakeVf[j].b_;
  Real fc = m_fakeVf[j].c_;
  CAL_NS_GAP(start, gap);
  // calculate gap mean for 5* 50000 samples
```

**cachegrind test result**
==15954== D   refs:       97,902,271,729  (72,009,552,612 rd   + 25,892,719,117 wr)
==15954== D1  misses:      1,813,482,789  ( 1,752,767,108 rd   +     60,715,681 wr)
==15954== LLd misses:         56,883,506  (    49,812,399 rd   +      7,071,107 wr)
==15954== D1  miss rate:             1.9% (           2.4%     +            0.2%  )
==15954== LLd miss rate:             0.1% (           0.1%     +            0.0%  )

**PS:**

My server is a virtual machine. The value function will be called about 234000000 times, alway; the vector elements keep unchanged during the proccess; My L1 data cache is 32K.

Comment: Show us the code, we can't help you if you don't show us where the problem might be.

Comment: There's an extra level of indirection if you use a vector. having a vector in your class is like having pointers in your class. It's not comparable to declaring a fixed length array in your class. But to truly understand the difference you need to look at the generated assembly code.

Comment: @rubenvb, in truth it is a part of code in quantlib, so it involved a large amount codes. Really difficult to display all of them. Let me take a carefully checking and give you the answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: @john, it works bad after I change vector to array. Will take a more careful examination. Thanks.

Comment: @naichuans: Don't display all the code - we need a minimal sample that's just barely large enough to show the problem. No more, no less.

Comment: @john: It's just 3*8000 bytes, that still fits into L1 cache. Indirection won't be a major problem.

Comment: It might help to put all data inside one array and arrange values as needed to get more cache hits?

Comment: There is probably some aliasing going on so the compiler can't be sure that `a_[j]` remains the same across the loop. When you assign it to a double you you make a copy and the compiler knows the copy doesn't alias with any of the function arguments. So it can keep the value in a register.

Comment: @rubenvb code and some test result have been added, plz check it, thanks

Comment: @MSalters plz check the code and other materials, thank you very much.

Comment: cachegrind:    
==15954== D   refs:       97,902,271,729  (72,009,552,612 rd   + 25,892,719,117 wr)    
==15954== D1  misses:      1,813,482,789  ( 1,752,767,108 rd   +     60,715,681 wr)    
==15954== LLd misses:         56,883,506  (    49,812,399 rd   +      7,071,107 wr)    
==15954== D1  miss rate:             1.9% (           2.4%     +            0.2%  )    
==15954== LLd miss rate:             0.1% (           0.1%     +            0.0%  )

Answer (score 2):

The gap may caused by cache filling. Try to re-order the vector as follows:

```
struct TT{
    double a_;
    double b_;
    double c_;
};
struct TT vector[999];
struct TT* p = &vector[j];
```

You can use `p` to access `a_`, `b_` and `c_` as you need.

Comment: hi, ol2sd2, I change three vector to a struct vector as your advice, the performance looks enhanced, but not enough.  the mean for 5*50000 samples is 226.2 ns.

Answer (score 0):

`aj = a_[j];` will likely have to come from the L1 cache, considering the array size. But `aj = fa;`? Chances are that this doesn't even take 1 instruction. The compiler might simply note that the two variables have the same value. Thus, in code later on that reads `aj`, the compiler simply reads `fa` instead.

Array access calculation on modern CPU's is close to free. x86 in particular can do an effectlive "load from Base plus Index * 8"

Comment: Hi, @MSalters, in my opinion, if my vector size don't exceed L1 cache size, the time consumed by vector access should be almost same. But it looks the time consume keep changes(Plz check the last set of test results I just posted). And my L1 data cache size is 32k

Comment: cachegrind show:    
==15954== D   refs:       97,902,271,729  (72,009,552,612 rd   + 25,892,719,117 wr)    
==15954== D1  misses:      1,813,482,789  ( 1,752,767,108 rd   +     60,715,681 wr)    
==15954== LLd misses:         56,883,506  (    49,812,399 rd   +      7,071,107 wr)    
==15954== D1  miss rate:             1.9% (           2.4%     +            0.2%  )    
==15954== LLd miss rate:             0.1% (           0.1%     +            0.0%  )